Stuck on a proof for the sum of the first n fourth powers
I am trying to prove that
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^4 = \frac{n^5}{5} + \frac{n^4}{2} + \frac{n^3}{3} - \frac{n}{30}$.
I will use these formulas:
$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} $
I know I can use a system of equations for the proof, but I'm trying to come up with a different way.
I noticed that we can rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^m i^2$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n i^4$ (where $m = n^2$) plus some other terms.
For instance, $\sum_{i=1}^{16} i^2 = 1^2 + (2^2 + 3^2) + 4^2 + (5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2) + 9^2 + (10^2 + 11^2 + 12^2 + 13^2 + 14^2 + 15^2) + 16^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{4} (i^2)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{4}[\sum_{j=1}^{2i-2}(j + (i-1)^2)^2]$.
For any n, $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\sum_{j=1}^{2i-2}[(j + (i-1)^2)^2] + i^4]$.
Knowing that $(j + (i - 1)^2)^2 = j^2 + 2ji^2 - 4ji +2j + i^4 - 4i^3 + 6i^2 - 4i + 1$, we write:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\sum_{j=1}^{2i-2} j^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{2i-2} (2i^2 - 4i + 2)j + (2i^4 - 4i^3 + 6i^2 - 4i + 1)$].
Evaluating the inner sums give us:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\frac{(2i-2)(2i-1)(4i-3)}{6} + (2i^2 -4i + 2)\frac{(2i-2)(2i-1)}{2} + (2i^4 - 4i^3 + 6i^2 - 4i + 1)]$.
Simplifying the summand and isolating the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^4$ term gives us:
$6\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^4 = \sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\frac{46i^3}{3} + 18i^2 - \frac{29i}{3} + 2 )$
Carrying out the sums leads to:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^4 = \frac{1}{6}[\frac{n^2(n^2+1)(2n^2+1)}{6} - (6n^3 + 9n^2 + 5n + \frac{-23n^4 - 46n^3 -52n^2 - 29n}{6})]$
The right side simplifies to $\frac{2n^6 + 26n^4 + 10n^3 - n^2 -n}{36}$.
I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the set-up given that our equation should have degree 5, but the $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i^2$ term ensures that we have degree 6. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thank you.

For an easier approach, that generalizes well, see this answer.

Your error lies within your evaluation of $\sum_{j=1}^{2i-2}\!\left(j+(i-1)^2\right)^2$. You're correct that $\left(j+(i-1)^2\right)^2=j^2+2ji^2-4ji+2j+i^4-4i^3+6i^2-4i+1$; however, $i$ is a constant with respect to the index $j$, and $\sum_{k=1}^n x=nx$. Therefore, after simplification, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2i-2}\left(j+(i-1)^2\right)^2=2i^5-6i^4+\frac{26i^3}{3}-8i^2+\frac{13i}{3}-1.$$
Furthermore, we also have
$$\frac{n^6}{3}+\frac{n^4}{2}+\frac{n^2}{6}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(2i^5-5i^4+\frac{26i^3}{3}-8i^2+\frac{13i}{3}-1\right).$$
Can you take it from there? (Hint: this answer will prove useful in reducing $\sum_{i=1}^n i^5$ to known quantities.)
